# Android: Keep screen on

Tags: android, android-fragments, keep-alive

I try to set the screen to always on however I cant figure out how to do it within a fragment. I have tried to get access to the ViewPager but it returns with a null value. I want the screen to be on for the whole application but it should be able to be changed by the user within the settings of the app.

Here is my code from within my fragment:

```
private void setIsAlwaysOn(boolean b)
{
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setKeepScreenOn(b);

    sharePropertiesEditor.putBoolean(sp_alwaysOn, b);
    sharePropertiesEditor.commit();
}
```

I get a nullpointerexception at line 4 of the visible code above.

Comment: I have tried that but I don't have access to the getWindow or currentWindow

Comment: In a Fragment getActivity().getWindow()

Comment: Post full stacktrace so we can see the context for the NPE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah. Can't you use this?

```
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

For Kotlin, use:

```
activity?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
```

Comment: With a getActivity() in front this worked perfectly :)